# Properly using logging.setLoggerClass() in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to create own Logger class and then reuse it in other modules.
Logger class is:
mypackage/log_class.py:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    
    def __init__(
        self, name = "MyLoggerName2222", log_file = None, 
        log_format = "%(asctime)s: Line %(lineno)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s"):

        self.formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
        self.log_file = log_file

        super().__init__(name=name)

        # Adding handlers
        self.addHandler(self.get_stream_handler())
        if log_file:
            self.addHandler(self.get_file_handler(log_file))

        self.propagate = True

    def get_stream_handler(self):
        """ Returns stream handler
        """
        # Initialize stream hamdler
        streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        
        # Logging level
        streamhandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        
        # Formatter
        streamhandler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        
        return streamhandler 

    def get_file_handler(self, log_file):
        """ Returns file handler
        """

        # Initialize stream hamdler
        filehandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=log_file, 
                                               when="midnight",
                                               backupCount=5)
 
        # Logging level
        filehandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        
        # Formatter
        filehandler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        
        return filehandler
```

The module is:
mypackage/main.py

```
from log_class import MyLogger
import logging

logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
logger = logging.getLogger("MyLogger", log_file="Test.log")

if __name__ == "__main__":    

    logger.debug("Debug message")
    logger.info("Info message")
```

I've got the

> TypeError: getLogger() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_file'
> When I remove log_file="Test.log" from the getLogger there are no errors, however no log message are shown. Neither in file nor in console.
> What exactly I'm doing wrong ?
> How to modify code in order to be able to provide log_file ?
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to get log messages in console. Hovewer still not clear how in this construction provide custom log file name...

Answer (score 0):

The method [logging.getLogger()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) accepts one keyword argument: `name = ''`.
You specify two arguments, of which the first is a positional argument and the second is a keyword argument with a key-name `log_file` that is not recognized.

When you change it to:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name="Test.log")
```

the code runs without errors.